# How to create fixed space and flexible space bar button items programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

I want to create `UIBarButtonItems` programmatically and place these fixed space items between buttons.

Answer (score 304, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *fixedItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
fixedItem.width = 20.0f; // or whatever you want

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
```

Comment: Note that to set the width of a Fixed Space UIBarButtonItem, you need to set the `.width` property.

Comment: perfect answer!

Comment: how can we have flexible width give equal spacing between all the buttons using code? I don't want to hard code width=20.0

Comment: Just put one flexible width between each two buttons @Satyam

Answer (score 18):

**Swift**

```
// Fixed Space
let fixedSpace: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
fixedSpace.width = 20.0

// Flexible Space
let flexibleSpace: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
UIBarButtonItem *todayItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Today" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(update_baritem:)];
todayItem.tag = 2;

UIBarButtonItem *cashItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cash" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(update_baritem:)];
cashItem.tag = 3;

UIBarButtonItem *creditItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Credit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(update_baritem:)];
creditItem.tag = 4;

UIBarButtonItem *allItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"All" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(update_baritem:)];
allItem.tag = 1;

UIBarButtonItem *returnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Return" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(update_baritem:)];
returnItem.tag = 5;

UIBarButtonItem *fixedItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[fixedItem setWidth:455.0f];

UIBarButtonItem *fixed2Item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[fixed2Item setWidth:37.0f];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

[self.toolbar setItems:@[fixed2Item, returnItem, creditItem, cashItem, fixedItem, todayItem, flexibleItem, allItem] animated:NO];
```

Comment: Why are you setting *right* bar button items to *left* items? That's just really bad style or a bug and I don't know which.

Answer (score 5):

As of this writing, if you're targeting iOS 14 and above, you can use the corresponding class functions to get fixed and flexible space items more concisely:

```swift
let fixedSpace = UIBarButtonItem.fixedSpace(20)
let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem.flexibleSpace()
```

Docs: [fixed space](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/3600338-fixedspace), [flexible space](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/3600339-flexiblespace)

Answer (score 3):

**In Swift:**

```
let fixedSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
fixedSpace.width = 20.0
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.1.2**

```
// Fixed Space
let fixedSpace: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
fixedSpace.width = 20.0

// Flexible Space
let flexibleSpace: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

In ViewDidLoad:

```
    //toolbar
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 416, 320, 44)];

// bar btns
UIBarButtonItem *backBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind target:self action:@selector(goBack)];
UIBarButtonItem *forwardBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward target:self action:@selector(goForward)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *bookmarkBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(bookmark)];
UIBarButtonItem *refreshBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh)];
UIBarButtonItem *stopLoadingBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemStop target:self action:@selector(stopLoading)];

// add btns to the bar
[toolBar setItems:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:bookmarkBtn,backBtn,forwardBtn,flexibleSpace,refreshBtn,stopLoadingBtn, nil]];

// adds the toobar to the view
[self.view addSubview:toolBar];
```

Do not forget the actions for each button also(in this example a UIWebView):

```
    -(void)goBack
{
    [_webView goBack];
}

-(void)goForward
{
    [_webView goForward];
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 3, `UIBarButtonItem` has an initializer called [`init(barButtonSystemItem:target:action:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617153-init). `init(barButtonSystemItem:target:action:)` has the following declaration:

```
convenience init(barButtonSystemItem systemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem, target: Any?, action: Selector?)
```

> Initializes a new item containing the specified system item.

---

[`UIBarButtonSystemItem`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonsystemitem) is an enumeration that offers many cases including `done`, `play`, `add` or `cancel`. However, according to your needs, you may also choose `flexibleSpace` or `fixedSpace` cases.

[`flexibleSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonsystemitem/1617162-flexiblespace) case has the following declaration:

> Blank space to add between other items. The space is distributed equally between the other items. Other item properties are ignored when this value is set.

[`fixedSpace`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonsystemitem/1617152-fixedspace) case has the following declaration:

> Blank space to add between other items. Only the `width` property is used when this value is set.

---

Therefore, you can create fixed and flexible space bar button items programmatically as shown below:

```
let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(
    barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace,
    target: nil,
    action: nil
)
```

```
let fixedSpace = UIBarButtonItem(
    barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.fixedSpace,
    target: nil,
    action: nil
)
fixedSpace.width = 30 // Set width with the appropriate value
```

---

As an example, the Playground code below shows how to add a bottom bar with two centered play and pause bar button items separated by a fixed space of 30 in a view controller:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        title = "Home"
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Show navigation controller’s built-in toolbar
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: false)

        // Create UIBarButtonItems
        let flexibleSpace1 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let playItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .play, target: self, action: nil)
        let fixedSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .fixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        fixedSpace.width = 30
        let pauseItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .pause, target: self, action: nil)
        let flexibleSpace2 = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

        // Set the view controller toolbar items
        setToolbarItems([flexibleSpace1, playItem, fixedSpace, pauseItem, flexibleSpace2], animated: false)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // Hide navigation controller’s built-in toolbar
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)

        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }

}

let viewController = ViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = navigationController
```

---

Preview your view controller in the Playground assistant editor using <kbd>View</kbd> ▸ <kbd>Assistant Editor</kbd> ▸ <kbd>Show Assistant Editor</kbd>

[image]