# Add empty space in navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios

I have 4 buttons in my navigation bar, but apparently the right one is too close to the side and the popover is not displaying correctly for it.

[image]

Is there a way to add some extra spacing to the right side? Like an empty button?
If an empty button is the solution then I know how to do it, just not sure if this is a right way to do it.

Comment: Can't you just increase the width of your buttons?

Comment: I already did that, when I increase it more it become kinda ugly, so I just want some spacing on the right of the last button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a **Flexible Space Bar Button Item** there.

Comment: Well I actually used `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace` instead of the flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this other Stack Overflow artcile about adding flexible space:

[How to create fixed space and flexible space bar button items programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663058/how-to-create-fixed-space-and-flexible-space-bar-button-items-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Place UIBarButtonItem between the specified place. Then go to Inspector of your xib, then go Attribute, select Flexible space option in Identifier option.