# Create Blank Space Between Nav Bar Items?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I've spent several hours on trying to figure this out to no end. My last option is to just create blank labels to create space, but I feel like their is a more cleaner way.

Basically I have three buttons and we're trying to create fixed space between them for neatness. Each button is programmatically added.

I found this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *fixedItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
fixedItem.width = 20.0f; // or whatever you want
```

([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663058/how-to-create-fixed-space-and-flexible-space-bar-button-items-programmatically))

But how do you assign this piece of code to a certain button?

Answer (score 10):

Its possible you're confused. You don't assign this code to a button. That code creates a button of type `UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace`. So, do what the answer you linked to says. Create the fixed & flexible `UIBarButtonItem`s (along with the other buttons you have), then set them on your navigation bar. In this case they would appear in the top left area of your navigation bar (via `leftBarButtonItems`):

```
// Create "Normal" buttons items:
UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"1" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:Nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *button2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"2" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:Nil action:nil];    
UIBarButtonItem *button3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"3" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:Nil action:nil];

// Create "Spacer" bar button items 
UIBarButtonItem *fixedItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
fixedItem.width = 20.0f; // or whatever you want
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[button1, fixedItem, button2, flexibleItem, button3];
```

Additionally, if you had a toolbar you could use the toolbar's `items` property:

```
self.toolbar.items = @[button1, fixedItem, button2, flexibleItem, button3];
```

Comment: The spacing works now with the buttons, however now that the buttons are spaced they no longer work with the selector actions specified. The buttons were created as UIButton(s) before and then placed in a navbar array as UIBarButtonItems which was how they were able to function before. How do you suppose I go about getting the functionality back?

Comment: We got it working! Thank you so much!! We had to change the target to "self".

Comment: I had assumed that UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace buttons were a default width.  This post by Aaron clued me in to the fact that I needed to set the width.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this in Interface Builder.
I tried to drag a Flexible or Fixed Space Bar Item, but it doesn't seem to work in a Navigation Bar.
Workaround: Drag a UIView between the Bar Buttons. Adjust the width of the UIView in the size inspector and set the color of view and Bar Button Item to clear color.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I wish there was a better way in IB though! Have you found any?

Answer (score 0):

You would add this button, potentially multiple times, into an array with the other buttons. Then you would set that array as the `rightBarButtonItems` (or `leftBarButtonItems`) or your view controllers navigation item.